# Servicemix spring context with JPA

Tags: jpa, osgi, eclipselink, apache-servicemix

I m having  a problem with ServiceMix and JPA.

I m new on servicemix and on the project I work for.

A bundle already exist to set the database configuration and contains a persistence.xml file with some properties in persistence-unit.

this persistent unit is for a postgresql database and work fine.

Recently someone add a new bundle. This bundle is a migration of an existing application that contains work to clean all table in relation with the treatment to have empty db -> readfile-> insert into db some data-> extract data into file for another application.

Now in OSGI bundle, we decide to create an H2 database with spring-context each time the process is launch. We work in memory and we don t have to clean all table with this solution.

So we have done a blueprint.xml that launch a bean, and the bean create a appContext = new OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext(...)

And when treatment is done we do appContext.close() and all spring context is destroy. (this treatment is run only once a day so no problem with time loading)

To do so we have an applicationContext.xml that contain

```
 <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
<property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
...


<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SingleConnectionDataSource">
....
 ....
```

All work fine, Spring Context is loaded with H2 in memory databse, and at the end of the treatment, h2 database not exist anymore.

Now the problem is when a query is launch on postgresql database, i have problem with insertion because entitymanager try to save entity with 0 id!

O id is meaning null because we don't allow-zero-id in persistence.xml for postgressql database, but in persistence.xml for H2 databse we set allow-zero-id to true and if the H2 treatment is launch only one time, the other entitymanager(postrgesql) don't work anymore and try to insert always 0 id in database instead of call sequence because of the allow-zero-id.

I don't now why the property for persistent unit defined in H2 databse ovveride property of persistence-unit of postgresql.

If someone can help? does new OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext(..) try to find an osgi service for entitymaneger and get an existing one instead of create à new one?

Comment: How are you passing in this property, and how are your persistence units differentiated from each other?  How are you persisting the entity with the 0 ID - is it explicitly passed to em.persist, or could this be some other entity referenced from a managed instance?  Turn on EclipseLink logging to see more details.

Comment: hello, i m having 2 separate persistence.xml file, each one have a persistence unit with different name, and property is in each persistent-unit. I think servicemix get a reference of the entitymanager and overide the firstly created. but i don't know how and where...